# Draw shapes on apple maps using XCUITest automation in Swift

Tags: swift4, ui-testing, xcuitest

```
Suppose if I have Four coordinates
 let app = XCUIApplication()
 let mapView = app.otherElements.matching(identifier: "map_view").element                                
 let co1 = mapView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 0.15))
 let co2 = mapView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 0.6))
 let co3 = mapView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 1, dy: 0.6))
 let co4 = mapView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 1, dy: 0.1))

 co1.press(forDuration: 2.0, thenDragTo: co2)
 co2.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: co3)
 co3.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: co4)
 co4.press(forDuration: 0, thenDragTo: co1)
```

I want to draw a closed path using the above one. When the 2nd line is drawn the first line disappears. I want to press once on the apple map and then drag to join the all four coordinates to form a closed path.

or else

Draw a circle with a certain radius on the map.

Comment: how to draw a polygon using XCUITest automation in swift language.

Answer (score 0):

You can not draw closed shapes while black box testing.

You can only draw lines (swipes, drag), circular paths (rotate) and some drawings with pinch, zoom.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement

If you want to draw complex shapes - you probably should switch to white box testing.

Comment: Even the Circular path also OK for me.